# Calculate all points of non negative integer values that lie on a plane

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization, runtime

We are given a plane defined by Ax+By+Cz-D = 0 where D is significantly larger than A,B,C and GCD(A,B,C) = 1. How would I find all points (x, y, z), where x,y,z are integers and >= 0, that lie on the plane in an efficient manner?

I tried bruteforcing the problem, finding the maximum value of x,y,z by calculating D/A, D/B and D/C and simply iterating through all the points in that area. However, this is not very efficient and takes a long time to do especially as D gets larger. I was wondering if there was a more efficient algorithm to do this or any optimizations I could make to solve the problem faster?

Python code for the bruteforce:

```
points = []
for x in range(d//z + 1):
    for y in range((d - a*x)//y + 1):
        z = (d - a*x - b*y)//c
        if a*x + b*y + c*z == d:
            points.append ((x,y,x))
```

Comment: Try solving the analogous problem with a line instead of a plane. If you have an equation like `x - 3y - 1 = 0`, do you really need to test all the integer pairs `(x,y)` to see if they're on the line? What if you find one or two points on the line -- would you then know where the others are?

Comment: I didn't work it out, but there should be some method using linear algebra (with rational numbers only, using shearing and scaling, no rotation) to change the basis of the plane to make it easy to enumerate the points on it.

Answer (score 0):

A Constraint Programming (CP) solver may help. Here I use the python-constraint package.

```
from constraint import *
A = 3; B = 4; C = 7; D = 1000
problem = Problem()
problem.addVariables(['x','y','z'],range(0,D+1))
problem.addConstraint(ExactSumConstraint(D,[A,B,C]))
solutions = problem.getSolutions()
print(f"number of solutions: {len(solutions)}")
display(solutions)
```

output:

```
number of solutions: 6036
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
[{'z': 142, 'y': 0, 'x': 2},
 {'z': 141, 'y': 1, 'x': 3},
 {'z': 140, 'y': 5, 'x': 0},
 {'z': 140, 'y': 2, 'x': 4},
 {'z': 139, 'y': 6, 'x': 1},
 {'z': 139, 'y': 3, 'x': 5},
 {'z': 139, 'y': 0, 'x': 9},
 {'z': 138, 'y': 7, 'x': 2},
 {'z': 138, 'y': 4, 'x': 6},
 {'z': 138, 'y': 1, 'x': 10},
 {'z': 137, 'y': 8, 'x': 3},
 {'z': 137, 'y': 5, 'x': 7},
 {'z': 137, 'y': 2, 'x': 11},
 {'z': 136, 'y': 12, 'x': 0},
 {'z': 136, 'y': 9, 'x': 4},
 {'z': 136, 'y': 6, 'x': 8},
 {'z': 136, 'y': 3, 'x': 12},
 {'z': 136, 'y': 0, 'x': 16},
 {'z': 135, 'y': 13, 'x': 1},
 {'z': 135, 'y': 10, 'x': 5},
 {'z': 135, 'y': 7, 'x': 9},
 {'z': 135, 'y': 4, 'x': 13},
 {'z': 135, 'y': 1, 'x': 17},
 {'z': 134, 'y': 14, 'x': 2},
 {'z': 134, 'y': 11, 'x': 6},
...
 {'z': 85, 'y': 39, 'x': 83},
 {'z': 85, 'y': 36, 'x': 87},
 {'z': 85, 'y': 33, 'x': 91},
 {'z': 85, 'y': 30, 'x': 95},
 ...]
```

This took 2.9s. Specifying the CP model takes just 4 lines of code. We could strengthen the bounds on the variables considerably. (I tried that: did not make a difference in solution time.)